# Interrupt process in samba share mounted folder breaks mount

Tags: mount, samba

I can successfully mount a Samba share on a local folder in Opensuse 12.1:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=<username>,password=<password> //<win-box>/<share> <mountpoint>
```

The problem comes if i interrupt (`^C`) for example a long `cp` process in `<mountpoint>`: I get

```
> cp -r BIG_FOLDER/ /tmp
^C
> ls
ls: reading directory .: Permission denied
```

The only solution I found is to `sudo umount <mountpoint>` then mount again.

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: I have a problem similar to this. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with CIFS and if I ^C a call to "find . -name -exec blah {} \;" then I get the behavior you describe. For me, fuser and lsof don't show any useful information. Perhaps a kernel bug or a CIFS / SAMBA bug.

Answer (score 1):

This bug does not seem to be in kernel version 2.6.32.

I have submitted this to the Debian kernel team:

See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=695492